# Ошибка при запуске приложения используя AssetSQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, android-room

Переписала свое приложение использовав Room. Приложение использует  готовую БД из папки assets/databases. Для его открытия использовала библиотеку `com.github.daolq3012:AssetSQLiteOpenHelper:V1.0.1`. Но при запуске приложения получаю ошибку (т.е. по какой-то причине не находит БД хотя она есть в папке). Такая же ошибка была на эмуляторе, но после того как удалила приложение и заново запустила на эмуляторе сработало. Хотелось бы разобраться и исправить эту проблему.

```
@Database(entities = {Plant.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract PlantDao plantDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "medplants.db";

    public static AppDatabase createPersistentDatabase(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                .build();
    }
}
```

> 2019-05-09 22:40:38.953 8137-8137/nata.medplants E/RecyclerView: No
>   adapter attached; skipping layout 2019-05-09 22:40:38.954
>   8137-8137/nata.medplants E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping
>   layout 2019-05-09 22:40:39.323 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog:
>   (11) database corruption at line 63165 of [605907e73a] 2019-05-09
>   22:40:39.324 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (11) Invalid page
>   count: nPage: 11567, nPageFile: 10757 2019-05-09 22:40:39.324
>   8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (11) lockBtree() error, rc: 11,
>   printing out first page (size: 1024) of  DB
>   /data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases/medplants.db 2019-05-09
>   22:40:39.324 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (11) database disk
>   image is malformed 2019-05-09 22:40:39.325 8137-8314/nata.medplants
>   E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: !@ Corruption reported by sqlite (11)
>   on database: /data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases/medplants.db
>   2019-05-09 22:40:39.325 8137-8314/nata.medplants
>   E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: !@ dbObj has been closed 2019-05-09
>   22:40:39.325 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler:
>   !@ DB Corruption has happened before this 2019-05-09 22:40:39.335
>   8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line
>   36356 of [605907e73a] 2019-05-09 22:40:39.335 8137-8314/nata.medplants
>   E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:36356: (2)
>   open(/data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases/medplants.db) -  2019-05-09
>   22:40:39.335 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Process
>   adzhi.medplants : Pid (8137) Uid (10518) Euid (10518) Gid (10518) Egid
>   (10518) 2019-05-09 22:40:39.335 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog:
>   (1) osStat failed "/data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases/medplants.db"
>   due to error (2) 2019-05-09 22:40:39.335 8137-8314/nata.medplants
>   E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases :
>   st_mode(40771) st_uid(10518) st_gid(10518) st_ino(282949) 2019-05-09
>   22:40:39.335 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of
>   /data/user/0/nata.medplants : st_mode(40700) st_uid(10518)
>   st_gid(10518) st_ino(282701) 2019-05-09 22:40:39.335
>   8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/user/0 :
>   st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(262147) 2019-05-09
>   22:40:39.335 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of
>   /data/user : st_mode(40711) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(196619)
>   2019-05-09 22:40:39.335 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat
>   of /data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(2)
>   2019-05-09 22:40:39.339 8137-8314/nata.medplants E/SQLiteDatabase:
>   Failed to open database
>   '/data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases/medplants.db'.
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error
>   (code 1294): Could not open database
>
> ########################################################### Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT) Caused By : Specified
>
> directory or database file does not exist. (unknown error (code 1294):
>   Could not open database)
>
> ########################################################### at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method) at
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:272)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:213)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:701)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:272)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:239)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1276)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1234)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:915)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:864)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.SQLiteAssetHelper.returnDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:429)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:422)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:178)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.AssetSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(AssetSQLiteOpenHelper.java:93)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.AssetSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(AssetSQLiteOpenHelper.java:70)
>   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:238) at
>   nata.medplants.interfaces.PlantDao_Impl$3.compute(PlantDao_Impl.java:216)
>   at
>   nata.medplants.interfaces.PlantDao_Impl$3.compute(PlantDao_Impl.java:202)
>   at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2019-05-09 22:40:39.343
>   8137-8314/nata.medplants E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   arch_disk_io_0 Process: nata.medplants, PID: 8137
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()' on a null object
>   reference at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:180)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.AssetSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(AssetSQLiteOpenHelper.java:93)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.AssetSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(AssetSQLiteOpenHelper.java:70)
>   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:238) at
>   nata.medplants.interfaces.PlantDao_Impl$3.compute(PlantDao_Impl.java:216)
>   at
>   nata.medplants.interfaces.PlantDao_Impl$3.compute(PlantDao_Impl.java:202)
>   at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2019-05-09 22:40:39.363
>   8137-8316/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line
>   36356 of [605907e73a] 2019-05-09 22:40:39.363 8137-8316/nata.medplants
>   E/SQLiteLog: (14) os_unix.c:36356: (2)
>   open(/data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases/medplants.db) -  2019-05-09
>   22:40:39.363 8137-8316/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Process
>   adzhi.medplants : Pid (8137) Uid (10518) Euid (10518) Gid (10518) Egid
>   (10518) 2019-05-09 22:40:39.363 8137-8316/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog:
>   (1) osStat failed "/data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases/medplants.db"
>   due to error (2) 2019-05-09 22:40:39.363 8137-8316/nata.medplants
>   E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases :
>   st_mode(40771) st_uid(10518) st_gid(10518) st_ino(282949) 2019-05-09
>   22:40:39.363 8137-8316/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of
>   /data/user/0/nata.medplants : st_mode(40700) st_uid(10518)
>   st_gid(10518) st_ino(282701) 2019-05-09 22:40:39.363
>   8137-8316/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of /data/user/0 :
>   st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(262147) 2019-05-09
>   22:40:39.363 8137-8316/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat of
>   /data/user : st_mode(40711) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(196619)
>   2019-05-09 22:40:39.363 8137-8316/nata.medplants E/SQLiteLog: (1) Stat
>   of /data : st_mode(40771) st_uid(1000) st_gid(1000) st_ino(2)
>   2019-05-09 22:40:39.366 8137-8316/nata.medplants E/SQLiteDatabase:
>   Failed to open database
>   '/data/user/0/nata.medplants/databases/medplants.db'.
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error
>   (code 1294): Could not open database
>
> ########################################################### Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT) Caused By : Specified
>
> directory or database file does not exist. (unknown error (code 1294):
>   Could not open database)
>
> ########################################################### at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method) at
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:272)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:213)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:701)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:272)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:239)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1276)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1231)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:915)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:864)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.SQLiteAssetHelper.returnDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:429)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:422)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:178)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.AssetSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(AssetSQLiteOpenHelper.java:93)
>   at
>   com.fstyle.library.helper.AssetSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(AssetSQLiteOpenHelper.java:70)
>   at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:238) at
>   nata.medplants.interfaces.PlantDao_Impl$3.compute(PlantDao_Impl.java:216)
>   at
>   nata.medplants.interfaces.PlantDao_Impl$3.compute(PlantDao_Impl.java:202)
>   at
>   androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: так, продолжайте

Comment: А есть кто-то кто может дать адекватный ответ?

Comment: для начала сформулируйте вопрос, добавьте информации итд

Comment: Вопрос простой. Как решить данную проблему? Скажите какой код добавить я добавлю. В вопрос добавила класс AppDatabase, в котором описана работа с БД

Comment: Вроде бы как в room имя базы указываеься без .db,  потом вроде как выполнять надо в отдельном потоке  .allowMainThreadQueries()

Comment: В других проектах класс, для работы с БД точно такой же, и работает. Попробовала убрав расширение .db вышла ошибка com.fstyle.library.helper.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/medplants file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable. На счет потока выборка из БД происходит используя RXJava